# Buttons don't execute correct commands [EDIT]

Tags: java, android, button, android-asynctask, android-studio

So I'm trying to make an app where there is an `ImageView` that displays a random image from a list of images. There are also two buttons, and based on the image, the correct button needs to be pressed. This keeps going and you get points until you get an incorrect answer.

I've used in Async methods to randomly display the image in ImageView, and set the conditions on my button. However, when I run the application, the condition only applies to the first image that's displayed. Afterwards, regardless of what image is displayed, the buttons conditions work as if the first image was displayed.

this is the code

```
public class Game extends ActionBarActivity {

static TextView timeDisplay;
int[] cardGallery =  {R.drawable.tile0, R.drawable.tile1, R.drawable.tile2, R.drawable.tile3, R.drawable.tile4, R.drawable.tile5, R.drawable.tile6, R.drawable.tile7, R.drawable.tile8, R.drawable.tile9};
int score = 0;
int imageId = (int) (Math.random() * cardGallery.length);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    ImageView cardImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cardImage);
    ImageButton bigButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.upButton);
    ImageButton smallButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.downButton);
    final TextView scoreDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreMessage);

    timeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerMessage);
    cardImageView.setImageResource(cardGallery[imageId]);
    scoreDisplay.setText("Current score: " + score);

   .
   .
   .

    bigButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /* may need to implement switch and cases for each button
            switch (cardGallery[imageId]){
                case R.drawable.tile0:
                    GameTimer.onFinish();
            }*/

            if (imageId == 0) {
                GameTimer.cancel();
                GameTimer.onFinish();
            }
            else if (imageId == 1) {
                GameTimer.cancel();
                GameTimer.onFinish();
            }
            else if (imageId == 2) {
                GameTimer.cancel();
                GameTimer.onFinish();
            }
            else if (imageId == 3) {
                GameTimer.cancel();
                GameTimer.onFinish();
            }
            else if (imageId == 4) {
                GameTimer.cancel();
                GameTimer.onFinish();
            }
            else if (imageId == 5) {
                GameTimer.start();
                scoreDisplay.setText("Current score: " + ++score);
                new CardAsyncTask().execute();
            }
            else if (imageId == 6) {
                GameTimer.start();
                scoreDisplay.setText("Current score: " + ++score);
                new CardAsyncTask().execute();
            }
            else if (imageId == 7) {
                GameTimer.start();
                scoreDisplay.setText("Current score: " + ++score);
                new CardAsyncTask().execute();
            }
            else if (imageId == 8) {
                GameTimer.start();
                scoreDisplay.setText("Current score: " + ++score);
                new CardAsyncTask().execute();
            }
            else if (imageId == 9) {
                GameTimer.start();
                scoreDisplay.setText("Current score: " + ++score);
                new CardAsyncTask().execute();
            }
            else {
                GameTimer.cancel();
                GameTimer.onFinish();
            }
    }});

        smallButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (imageId == 0) {
                GameTimer.start();
                scoreDisplay.setText("Current score: " + ++score);
                new CardAsyncTask().execute();
            }
            else if (imageId == 1) {
                GameTimer.start();
                scoreDisplay.setText("Current score: " + ++score);
                new CardAsyncTask().execute();
            }
            else if (imageId == 2) {
                GameTimer.start();
                scoreDisplay.setText("Current score: " + ++score);
                new CardAsyncTask().execute();
            }
            else if (imageId == 3) {
                GameTimer.start();
                scoreDisplay.setText("Current score: " + ++score);
                new CardAsyncTask().execute();
            }
            else if (imageId == 4) {
                GameTimer.start();
                scoreDisplay.setText("Current score: " + ++score);
                new CardAsyncTask().execute();
            }
            else if (imageId == 5) {
                GameTimer.cancel();
                GameTimer.onFinish();
            }
            else if (imageId == 6) {
                GameTimer.cancel();
                GameTimer.onFinish();
            }
            else if (imageId == 7) {
                GameTimer.cancel();
                GameTimer.onFinish();
            }
            else if (imageId == 8) {
                GameTimer.cancel();
                GameTimer.onFinish();
            }
            else if (imageId == 9) {
                GameTimer.cancel();
                GameTimer.onFinish();
            }
            else {
                GameTimer.cancel();
                GameTimer.onFinish();
            }
        }
    });




}





class CardAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        int imageId = (int) (Math.random() * cardGallery.length);
        return imageId;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer imageId) {
        ImageView cardImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cardImage);
        cardImageView.invalidate();
        cardImageView.setImageResource(cardGallery[imageId]);
    }

}
```

}

i think it's because i've declared the old and new imageId values as the same, but if I were to change them to say imageId and newimageId, this would change the conditions in my code where I call for values to be compared to imageId.
Thanks

Comment: Post your code so that we can figure it out.

Comment: Please also have look at: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: just added it. apologise if it looks messy and badly written. I'm trying to get the hand of things.

Comment: @hofmeister sorry about that will remember for next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple variables named imageId. Here's what's happening:

1) You declare a variable in your Game class, named imageId, with the line:

```
int imageId = (int) (Math.random() * cardGallery.length);
```

This is on the 6th line down in your code sample. Each instance of your Game class will have a member named imageId, which is assigned a random value when the instance is created (i.e. when your activity is created).

2) In your doInBackground method of the CardAsyncTask class, you then declare a local variable, also named imageId, and assign it a random value. As you have declared a local variable, assigning a value to it will have no effect on the imageId variable stored in your Game class. The imageId in doInBackground is then returned from that method, and is passed by the AsyncTask as a parameter to the onPostExecute method, where you use it to update your image view.

Your two options then are:

a) Remove the "int" from the variable declaration inside doInBackground, so that instead of creating a local variable inside the function, the doInBackground task will modify the imageId in the Game class instance. This, however, is a bad idea. Because doInBackground is running on a background thread, there is a possibility of the following sequence of events:

- doInBackground runs, and modifies imageId
- The user then presses the button before onPostExecute has run. The old image will be showing, but the new imageId has been set.
- The onPostExecute will then run, setting the image to the new image.

Admittedly, the user probably won't notice that it happened out of order, but it's always best to think about these things when working with asynchronous processes.

b) The better option would be to set the Game instance's imageId field to the new imageId when you change the image, in onPostExecute. You also have a local variable named imageId in that function, which is the parameter that has been passed in. What I'd suggest is:

In doInBackground, rename imageId to newImageId:

```
protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    int newImageId = (int) (Math.random() * cardGallery.length);
    return newImageId;
}
```

Then in onPostExecute, assign the new image ID to the field in the Game class:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Integer newImageId) {
    ImageView cardImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cardImage);
    cardImageView.invalidate();
    cardImageView.setImageResource(cardGallery[newImageId]);
    imageId = newImageId;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks! This did the trick! Yeah I knew calling imageId in both parts was the problem (I commented about it after the code). I tried doing exactly what you were doing but declared newImageId = imageId (wrong way around) in the doInBackground section. Thanks again!!